# Adding Search Bar into Flatlist using Hook, Undefined

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, hook, react-native-flatlist, searchbar

i try to create flatlist inside modal with search bar functionality that can filter the result based on user input in the search bar.

For the flatlist everything show up accordingly,
problem i can't filter the data,
i try using .filter from the original full data (list) but result is always undefined is not a data.

Btw data is populate from local .json file to state using useEffect.

Here is the local country.json data  :

```
[
"Japan", 
"Korea", 
"Thailand", 
"Indonesia" ]
```

Here is part of the source code  :

```
import dataCountry from '../../assets/json/country.json';
```

const NameScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

```
// hook
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
const [modalBirthplace, setModalBirthplace] = useState(false);
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    setList({ dataCountry });
    console.log('check List : ', list);
}, [])

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
);

const ListItem = ({ title }) => (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("ok")}>
            <Text style={styles.cityList}>{title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);

const searchFilterFunction = searchText => {

    setSearchText(searchText);
    console.log(searchText)

    const newData = list.filter((item) => { // error trigger from this list.filter undefined is not a function
        const itemData = item.toUpperCase();
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });

    setList(newData);
};

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalBirthplace}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
            }}>
            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                <View style={styles.modalView}>
                    <Text style={styles.modalText}>Choose your country location :</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Try japan maybe?"
                        onChangeText={searchText => searchFilterFunction(searchText)}
                        value={searchText}
                    />
                    <FlatList
                        data={list.dataCountry}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <ListItem
                                title={item}
                            />
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={item => item}
                    />
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: '#E15C72' }}
                        onPress={() => {
                            setModalBirthplace(!modalBirthplace);
                        }}>
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Close Selection</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    </View>
)
```

}

Anybody know why i can't filter the state?

Thanks a lot before

Comment: is the error that occurs when you type something in the search bar?

Comment: yes, when i type in the search bar the error occur, I suspect is in the list.filter, i'm test it using empty array, let say i have const [arrayholder, setArrayholder] = useState(''); and i put arrayholder.filter then no error. but with this list that contain my full data it's always undefined it's time i type something in the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your state is an JSON object, not an array:

```
setList({ dataCountry });
// so list is: 
{
  dataCountry: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

so, you need to change here

```
const newData = list.dataCountry.filter((item) => { // here
        const itemData = item.toUpperCase();
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });

    setList({dataCountry: newData}); // and here
```

Comment: Hi i see, i try to log it and yes it's state contain object and inside it an array. Thank you. Btw i try it, and it can filter, everytime i type character it's already filtering the result now, but if i delete the character (backspace), why the filter result not refreshing?

Comment: @abet because the origin array has changed. but it is another problem, so i think you need to fugure it out by yourself

Comment: Noted! i manage it by creating other state to keep the original array, so each time search function is called i'm not updating the original array. I don't know it's good practice or not but it's work. Thank you again @Quang Thái

Answer (score 1):

maybe your json like this,

```
 const list = {
  dataCountry : [
    'UK',
    'US'
  ]
}
```

List is an object you can't use the filter with an object.
Instead of using array placeholder you can use spread operator like this,

```
const newData = [...list.dataCountry].filter((item) => { 
  const itemData = item.toUpperCase();
  const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
  return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
});
```